# Why my ShardWorker is not running in Firefox but running in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-worker, shared-worker

I finally implemented running Server-Sent Event SSE in a Shared Worker. This implementation allowed me to restrict the total scripts running on the server to one per user.

However, I am still having couple of issues.

1. The `SharedWorker` does not run at all in FireFox but it runs in Google Chrome. I am using firefox v40.0. I do not get any errors in the console. I do see a warning in the console about the SSL cert but no errors. Here is the warning from FireFox console

> This site makes use of a SHA-1 Certificate; it's recommended you use
>   certificates with signature algorithms that use hash functions
>   stronger than SHA-1.[Learn More]

2. It seems that `ShardWorker` stops working after a while of idle time. This is not a PHP script issue as the script works file without the shared worker. I am running into this issue with Chrome v44.0. for the shardworker to start again, I have to reload the page.

What can I do to figure out what could be causing the ShardWorker to stop?
Why isn't `SharedWorder` running in FireFox?

Here is my implementation

This is the code hat calls the `SharedWorker`

```
$(window).load(function(){
    //establish connection to the shared worker
    var worker = new SharedWorker("/add-ons/icws/js/worker.js");
    //listen for a message send from the worker
    worker.port.addEventListener("message",
        function(event) {
            console.log(event.data);
            processServerData(event.data);
        }
        , false
    );

    //start the connection to the shared worker
    worker.port.start();
});
```

Here is the code for `worker.js`

```
var clients = new Array();

//runs only when a new connection starts
self.onconnect = function(event) {

    var port = event.ports[0];
    clients.push(port);
    port.start();

    //implement a channel for a communication between the connecter and the SharedWorker
    port.addEventListener("message",
        function(event) { 
            replyToClientMessage(event, port);
        } , false
    );

}

//reply to any message sent to the SharedWorker with the same message but add the phrase "SharedWorker Said: " to it
replyToClientMessage = function (event, port) {
    port.postMessage(event.data);

}

readNewMessages();

//runs every time and post the message to all the connected client
 function readNewMessages(){
    var serv = new EventSource('/add-ons/icws/poll.php');
        serv.addEventListener("getMessagingQueue", function(event) {

        var queue = JSON.parse(event.data);
        notifyAllPorts(queue);

    }, false);
}

//check all open clients and post a message to each
 function notifyAllPorts(msg){

    var len = clients.length;
    var port;

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        port = clients[i];
        port.postMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried removing `self` at `self.onconnect` ? Is `EventSource` defined within worker scope ?

Comment: I just removed `self` from the code, nothing changed. Chrome is still working and FireFox not. I am doing testing to see if this solved for the timeout issues. The only time `EventSource` call is on this line `var serv = new EventSource('/add-ons/icws/poll.php');` I am not sure if this answer your question or not

Comment: Tried adding error handlers to workers ?

Comment: @guest271314 I think you are onto something. I added this code the the calling script `worker.onerror = function(event){ console.log(event);};` Here is what I got `error { target: SharedWorker, isTrusted: true, message: "ReferenceError: EventSource is not defined", filename: "https://example.com/add-ons/icws/js/worker.js", lineno: 28, colno: 0, currentTarget: SharedWorker, eventPhase: 2, bubbles: false, cancelable: true, defaultPrevented: false }`  how/where would I define EventSource it?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorkerGlobalScope , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Functions_and_classes_available_to_workers

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the solution. does this mean EventSource can't be used because it is not part of the workerGlobalScope?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88420/discussion-between-mike-a-and-guest271314).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make EventSource available inside SharedWorker in FireFox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32321295/how-to-make-eventsource-available-inside-sharedworker-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible . `EventSource` is property of `window` object . `window` is not available to `Worker` . See [Features Available to Workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/#toc-enviornment-features)

> Workers do NOT have access to:
>
> - The DOM (it's not thread-safe)
> - The window object
> - The document object
> - The parent object